# Error: no match for 'operator+' operand types are 'std::vector <int>' and 'int' in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

> Error: no match for 'operator+' operand types are 'std::vector <int>' and 'int' in c++

Why is this showing an error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "enter the total no. of elements you want in the array : \n";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    int inpt;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "enter the element you want in the array : \n";
        cin >> inpt;
        arr.push_back(inpt);
    }
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (abs(arr[j] - i) == abs(arr[j + 1] - (i + 1))) {
                v.push_back(arr[j]);
                v.push_back(arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    int s = v.size();
    int s1 = s;
    if (s == n) {
        while (v[s] < v[s - 1]) {
            s--;
        }
        int h = v[s - 1];
        while (v[s1] < v[h]) {
            s1--;
        }
        int c = v[s1];
        std::swap(v[h], v[c]);
        std::reverse(&v[h + 1], v + n);
        for (auto m = v.begin(); m != v.end(); ++m) {
            std::cout << *m << ' ';
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "-1";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I correct this, what did I do wrong?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: What do you expect `v + n` to do?

Comment: `std::reverse(&v[h+1],v+n);`: `v` is a vector not a pointer, so you can't do pointer arithmetic with it.  Did you mean `&v[n]`?

Comment: `arr[j + 1]` looks like you access several elements beyond the end of your arr array. I mean if j+1 is greater than or equal to n you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The std::reverse algorithm requires two iterators, first and last. Both must be within the range of the same container.
In your case: `std::reverse(&v[h+1],v+n);`
Both of them point at the wrong data. First: `&v[h+1]` is address to value in the container, not an iterator. Second is invalid because `std::vector+int` just wouldn't work, as there's no operator+ overload in the `std::vector`.
What you want is `v.begin()+h+1` for the first one, and `v.begin()+n` for the second to obtain iterators. The `vector::iterator` has `operator+` and `operator++` overloads, so it can accept index values.

A hint! Remember that C++ has zero based indexing, so a vector size 10 can only be accessed via indexes between 0 and 9! Make sure you correct that in your code.